# Telerik RadHtmlChart skip days in x-axis

Tags: telerik, radhtmlchart

I am using Telerik RadHtmlChart ([the chart screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htFxk.jpg)), I need to remove from the x axis Saturdays and Sundays. What I mean, I need that the distance between friday and Monday be the same as Monday to Tuesday, my data will return only information for day weeks not for weekend.

It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an actual date axis this will not be possible.

If you use a categorical x-axis it will be, but you will have to create axis items yourself and provision for that in the data source you have